# Error:(252, 5) error: invalid attribute format ''.? How to get a clean .gradle folder rebuild?

Tags: android

CORRECTION TO MY QUESTION: I realized the problem is I accidentally deleted some generated files under .gradle and now its yelling at me for missing those xml files. I tried `Build->Clean Project` and manually deleting the `.gradle` folder but neither worked. How do I get a clean .gradle folder? Do I delete other stuff too?

Comment: put it in the "dimens" folder

Comment: this was generated

Comment: Put the entry ( `<dimen name="abc_action_bar_content_inset_material">16dp</dimen>` ) in `...\app\src\main\res\values\dimens.xml` . Create a `dimens.xml` **file** if you don't have one.

Comment: See my update to the question after I got this initial part working.

Answer (score 0):

make separate file for dimens.xml file in values folder then put your dimens like below.. if you want not 
compulsory you can put dimens in values file.

```
<resources>
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="nav_header_vertical_spacing">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="nav_header_height">176dp</dimen>
<dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

then used in xml like below ..

```
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

Comment: See my update to the question after I got this initial part working.

Answer (score 0):

create a dimens.xml file inside values folder then inside that file put your code like :

```
 <resources>

      <dimen name="abc_action_bar_content_inset_material">16dp</dimen>

 </resources>
```

Comment: See my correction to the question after I got this initial part working.